# Count authors of a bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, macros, bibliographies, latex3, author-number

I would like to have a command that would give me the number of authors of a given bib entry. What I have unsuccessfully attempted so far was to create a key-value storage (prop), hook on the bbl import mechanism and store the number of authors which is supposed to be present in the author counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {John Doe and Mike Smith},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
    }
    @book{key2,
        author = {John Doe},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Title2},
        publisher = {Publisher2},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_my_author_count
\cs_new_protected:Npn \storecount#1#2{%
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_my_author_count{#1}{#2}%
}
\cs_new:Npn \getcount#1{%
    \prop_item:Nn \g_my_author_count{#1}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{authorcount}
\setcounter{authorcount}{0}

\AtDataInput{%
    \storecount{\strfield{entrykey}}{\value{author}}%
    % debug stuff begin
        \storecount{fakekey}{123}%
        \addtocounter{authorcount}{\value{author}}%
        \global\edef\entrykey{\strfield{entrykey}}%
    % debug stuff end
}

% make sure it's defined
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{entrykey}{\edef\entrykey{\empty}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    % debug stuff begin
        % expect 3
        \arabic{authorcount} % got 3 => hook & counter work

        % expect key or key2
        \entrykey % got key => \strfield{entrykey} works

        % expect [?] - 123
        [?] - \getcount{fakekey}    % got [?] - 123
                                    % => storage works
    % debug stuff end

    % expect [2] - 2
    \cite{key} - \getcount{key} % got [2] - 

    % expect [1] - 1
    \cite{key2} - \getcount{key2} % got [1] -   

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, I don't get what does not work as you expected in your code and what is your intended result.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry about that. I have put the expected output in the comments inside the code block. I will try to formulate my questions better next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the information is present in the `author` counter when an entry is processes, the number can be retrieved directly with a `\cite...`-like command. No detour via `\AtDataInput` is necessary.

Since the `biblatex`'s `\cite` commands are robust, this does not give you back the number of authors in an expandable manner. Should that be needed, it might indeed be easier to go through `\AtDataInput` or let a `\cite` like command save the relevant counter in a helper macro. What makes more sense will depend on the use case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorcount}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext{The entry}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printfield{entrykey}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printtext{has \arabic{author} author(s)}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\citeauthorcount{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> The entry sigfridsson has 2 author(s), The entry worman has 1 author(s)

---

If I understand correctly, the main issue with your `expl3` solution was expansion and a missing `\the`. The MWE used `n`-type arguments and so would not store the values of the counter, but rather its internal representation and similarly for `\strfield{entrykey}`: The `n` version would just save `\strfield{entrykey}`, but the `x` version expands this and so writes `sigfridsson` and `worman`. The following implementation should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_vh_author_count

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vh_store_author_count:nn #1#2
{
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_vh_author_count {#1} {#2}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vh_store_author_count:nn {xx}

\cs_new:Npn \vh_get_author_count:n #1
{
  \prop_item:Nn \g_vh_author_count {#1}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \getauthorcount {m} {
  \vh_get_author_count:n { #1 }
}

\AtDataInput{%
  \vh_store_author_count:xx {\strfield{entrykey}}{\the\value{author}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{sigfridsson} - \getauthorcount{sigfridsson}

  \cite{worman} - \getauthorcount{worman}

  \edef\foo{\getauthorcount{worman}} \meaning\foo

  \edef\foo{\getauthorcount{sigfridsson}} \meaning\foo

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [1] - 2
>
> [2] - 1
>
> macro:->1
>
> macro:->2

Comment: I needed to get the number in an expandable manner, so the correction to my expl3 attempt solves it for me. Thank you.